# Impersonating a sharepoint site to open it with custom account

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How to create a sharepoint 2007 site by impersonating with custom account, so that it wont show login prompt box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469253.aspx) constructor where you pass [SPUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusertoken.aspx) object
To get token of some user, use [SPWeb.AllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allusers.aspx)["userLoginName"].UserToken

Comment: Thanks Janis for your response,
In my case I dont want sharepoint site to prompt for login, my site is accesible to anonymous users, so when I am impersonating using 'SPWeb.AllUsers["userLoginName"].UserToken' it is prompting for login. How to impersonate without that login prompt.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. How would it prompt for a login when you do things in code behind? Where are you putting that code in and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that to be able get a user token you should be running your code with elevated priviledges and that might be why is pompting for login (beacuse the anonimous user doesnt have permissions to get another users token)

Example

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {           
   //is important that you instantiate your SPSite object within you elevated code        
              using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("your site URL"))
                    {

                        using (SPWeb oWeb = "your web")
                        {
                          //your code to run elevated 
                        }
                    }
            });
```